# Android Studio Unit Testing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

I am doing the unit testing on android studio, I create a test case in test class and on every time when I run that it give different output but when I debug it give me fine out put.It may be problem of caching or something else. I have also tried Invalidate studio and clean project but still occurring. Please Help.

Comment: Have you disabled the device's animations before launching the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `@Before` method, make sure to use `Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)` to make sure the app is not already running in the background of your test when you begin testing. This could be what is introducing your cache issue.

to clarify, your `@Before` method should look something like this:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    //Initialize UiDevice instance
    Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(instrumentation);

    mDevice.pressHome();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.REDACTED.auto.diagnostics.dealer.MAIN");
    intent.setClassName("com.REDACTED.auto.diagnostics", "com.REDACTED.auto.diagnostics.dealer.MainActivity");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

There are simpler ways to do this if you have the source code, however in my case I did not